# How do I call cardinality in type theory?

Tags: cardinals, type-theory

In set theory, we say *"cardinality"* when we mean *"how many members are there in a set"*. Is there a corresponding notion in type theory? *(Any thereof)*

For example, I have the idea that the functions of type $X \to Y$ are $Y^X$ in number. But I cannot explain how I arrived to this thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in general, no. Types are not "collections of things". The closest you can get to this with a fair amount of generality is to look at the number of closed (normal form) terms of the given type. This more or less corresponds to looking at the number of [global elements](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/global+element) categorically speaking. The problem is the closed terms/global elements rarely tell you everything about a type in most type theories. The interesting thing about (usual) set theories is that the global elements tell you *everything* there is to know about a set. Returning to type theory, we can have, for example, a type that has *no* closed terms/global elements, and yet is still distinct from the empty type.

As a concrete example of this phenomenon in a relatively well-known type theory we have the [circle type](https://ncatlab.org/homotopytypetheory/show/circle), $\mathbb S^1$, in [Homotopy Type Theory](https://homotopytypetheory.org/) (HoTT). This type has only one closed term, and yet it is quite distinct from the unit type. A function $f:\mathbb S^1\to X$ not only has to map the global element from $\mathbb S^1$ to $X$, but it also needs to map the path in $\mathbb S^1$ to a path in $X$. Two functions $\mathbb S^1\to X$ can differ on how they map the path even if they agree on how they map the global element. The intuition from classical homotopy theory is that $f$ is continuous and defined for all the "points" of the circle $\mathbb S^1$ even though we can only name one of those "points".

In many richer type theories, e.g. descendants of [Martin-Löf type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory) (MLTT), you can define (or have axiomatically) finite types. For example, in [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php), a variation on MLTT, you can define:

```
data ℕ : Set where -- Don't let the word "Set" mislead you. "Type" would be a better name.
    Z : ℕ
    S : ℕ → ℕ

data Fin : ℕ → Set where
    FZ : {n : ℕ} → Fin (S n)
    FS : {n : ℕ} → Fin n → Fin (S n)
```

`Fin n` where `n : ℕ` is now a type that has `n` closed, normal form terms, which will look like `FZ`, `FS FZ`, `FS (FS FZ)`, etc. You could then attempt to prove `(Fin n -> Fin m) ≅ Fin (m^n)` where `m^n` is an implementation of exponentiation of natural numbers (You may need to assume function extensionality. I haven't tried it.) By `≅` I mean an explicit isomorphism, i.e. a pair of functions going opposite directions and a pair of proofs show that they are mutually inverse.

For an analogue to the general theory of (infinite) cardinals and ordinals, it takes a fairly rich type theory just to formulate the problem. My understanding is that, for at least typical constructive type theories, there isn't really a meaningful/useful notion of "cardinal".